# Dart: SecurityError when getting ImageData from Context

Tags: html5-canvas, dart, dartium

I'm not sure why, but I get this error:

> Breaking on exception: SecurityError: Internal Dartium Exception

When I try to get a ImageData from a context of a Canvas I have filled with an external Url.
I suppose the problem is that the image on the canvas does not come from the same url as my code. Is it the case?

```
ImageData id = mainContext.getImageData(0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);
```

The rest of the code works and it's just the creation of the canvas and its context. I draw an image on the canvas

```
ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: fileNameElement.value);
image.onLoad.listen((e) {
  mainCanvas.width= image.width;
  mainCanvas.height = image.height;
  mainContext.drawImage(image,0,0);
});
```

Comment: If this was HTML5: Your `<canvas>` is tainted with external content and you cannot export its content anymore. This is to prevent stealing data from external sites. I guess Google applies the same security principles on Dartium and you need to somehow make those external image resources CORS-aware; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

Comment: Ok then, I suppose I have to find another way to get to the images, maybe with copy and paste but it seems tricky to do as well.

Comment: Or just make a server-side proxy loader which loads them from the same origin.

Comment: From the point of view of the user, having him do a "copy URL" or a "copy Image" is almost the same thing. Copy Image has the advantages to be usable even when the image is local. I could probably do both.